# Search Through Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

All,

I have a core data entity, `CreditCard`, and each entity has four values.

So, what I need to do is search through ALL of my `CreditCard` entities and find the one with a property `pocketNum` that is equal to whatever value the user puts in, and then return it so I can pull necessary values from it.

How would I do this?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `NSFetchRequest` with `NSPredicate`:

```
// 'moc' is your NSManagedObjectContext instance
// 'yourPockerNum' is what you want to find

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CreditCard" inManagedObjectContext:moc]
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = entity;
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pocketNum == %@", yourPocketNum];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

// do something with results
```

Comment: I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the request.predicate line. Not sure why. But this looks like what I need.

Comment: It's because `yourPocketNum` variable. Check for any memory management problems with it.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks a lot!